# SQL select subquery no result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Id like to use an subquery in my select statement. Something like:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE a = '1') AS countsubquery, fielda,fieldb
FROM testtable
WHERE a = 'b'
```

But when the subquery is empty te whole row get deleted from the result. So when subquery = null and fielda en field b are filled this row gets deleted from the result because countsubquery = null.

Is there an way that the result is:

```
countsubquery = null
fielda = filled
fieldb = filled
```

In my case the subquery need to be in the select statement.

Thanks!

** edit **
Real query:

```
SELECT (driver.[Initials]+' '+driver.[Driver Name]) AS bedrijdernaam,
        driver.[Function] AS functie,
        leasecardriver.[Driver Code] AS personeelsnummer,
        leasecar.[Car Brand Code] AS automerk,
        leasecar.[Car Type Code] AS autotype,
        leasecar.[License No_] AS kenteken,
        (SELECT SUM(fuel.Amount) FROM [EXAMPLEDATA$Fuel Table] AS fuel 
            WHERE fuel.[Perpetration Date] >= '--01 00:00:00' 
            AND fuel.[Perpetration Date] <= '--29 11:59:00' 
            AND fuel.personnelnumber = leasecardriver.[Driver Code]) AS verbruik,
            leasecardriver.[Driver Code] AS personeelsnummer1,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),leasecontract.[Expected Contract ending date],105) AS einddatum 
            FROM [EXAMPLEDATA$Lease Contract] AS leasecontract 
LEFT JOIN [EXAMPLEDATA$Lease Car] AS leasecar ON leasecontract.[License No_] = leasecar.[License No_] 
LEFT JOIN [EXAMPLEDATA$Lease Company] AS leasecompany ON leasecompany.Code = leasecontract.[Lease Company Code] 
LEFT JOIN [EXAMPLEDATA$Lease Car Driver] AS leasecardriver ON leasecardriver.license = leasecar.[License No_] 
LEFT JOIN [EXAMPLEDATA$Driver] AS driver ON leasecardriver.[Driver Code] = driver.[Driver] 
WHERE (leasecontract.[Status] = '0' OR leasecontract.[Status] = '1') 
AND (((driver.[Voornaam]+' '+driver.[Driver Name]) LIKE '%%') OR (leasecar.[License No_] LIKE '%%') OR (driver.[Cost place code] LIKE '%%') OR (driver.[BusinessLine (GP)] LIKE '%%') OR (driver.[Salaris Unit (GP)] LIKE '%%') OR (leasecardriver.[Driver Code] LIKE '%%'))
```

It is subuery after : "leasecar.[License No_] AS kenteken,"

Comment: I think you need correlated sub query instead to link `table2` and `testtable`

Comment: I have feeling this is a sample query - provide a real query, because the sample query wouldn't work (there is no field named "a" in the main query

Comment: Regardless the subquery returning results or not, the outer query will return the row. The only way to not return the row is that the where clause evaluates to false.

Comment: what I would suggest is, in your subquery to remove the `Where` conditions on by one if you then get a result you'll know who is the trouble maker...

Answer (score 0):

Would add this as a comment if I had the rep.

If I understand it correctly, the syntax goes on for you, but you are having issues with the records where the subquery's result is null. In this case, I think this is worth a look:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

You can assign an alternate value if the result is NULL, so this should also show up in your result set.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Theoretically should this solution work but it does not help in this case..

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE a = '1'),0) AS countsubquery,
   fielda,fieldb
FROM testtable
WHERE a = 'b'
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Theoretically should this solution work but it does not help in this case..